# Calling an API action from another API, reading the json response and adding some extra properties to it

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a .netcore web api(localApi) that calls another web api(remoteApi).
remoteApi returns json and my goal is to add a new property to that json and return it as json to the caller calling localApi.

So far my code is like this:

```
                var httpResponse = await httpClient.PostAsync(remoteApi), httpContent);

                // If the response contains content we want to read it!
                if (httpResponse.Content != null)
                {
                    responseContent = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                    responseContent = responseContent.Insert(2, " \"isCachedResponse\": false,");

                    var retVal = await Task.Run(() => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(responseContent));
                    return Ok(retVal);
                }
```

The problem with this approach is that the response is a string and not json.
Like below:

```
"\"{ \"isCachedResponse\": true, \\\"remoteApiResponse\\\":{ \\\"applicationId\\\":\\\"10001000000300071\\\", \\\"reasons\\\":[ { \\\"reason\\\":\\\"Score Cut Policy\\\" } ], \\\"decisionText\\\":\\\"Duplicate request; check UI for more information\\\", \\\"decisionCode\\\":\\\"Undecisioned\\\", \\\"officialNameOnFile\\\":{ \\\"firstName\\\":\\\"\\\", \\\"middleName\\\":\\\"\\\", \\\"lastName\\\":\\\"\\\" } } }\""
```

How can I get around this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just return a plain string `ContentResult` because you already have the required JSON instead of starting some additional tasks, doing some manual serialization and returning an `OkObjectResult`:

```
if (httpResponse.Content != null)
{
    responseContent = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    responseContent = responseContent.Insert(2, " \"isCachedResponse\": false,");

    return this.Content(responseContent, "application/json");
}
```

Comment: Great explanation along with sample code. I hope this helps anyone else in my spot as well. Thank you...